# Python Pandas Convert String to int/float

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that I am trying to manipulate so that the 'amount' column converts from a string ("hh.hh 'hours'") to an int or float.

I am wondering what the best practice is in this situation. I have tried pd.to_numeric(), but without success. I think my problem is with the 'hours' tacked on the end of each string.

Is there another function that will identify numeric characters and simply ignore the 'hours' portion of the string, or do I first need to trim the last 5 characters before working with the built in dtype conversion function (pd.to_numeric)? Thanks!

```
           day  amount
2018-08-23  3   24.00 hours
2018-08-24  4   8.00 hours
2018-08-25  5   32.00 hours
2018-08-26  6   24.00 hours
2018-08-27  0   24.00 hours
```

Comment: Trimming `'hours'` would be easiest i think. should be pretty quick to do

Comment: Thanks. I had encountered a parser function imported from dateutils in the past when working with time series data (used for converting something to the tune of 'Jul 4th, 2018 10:30 AM' into a datetime() object). I was curious to know if there was something similar built into pandas that I haven't stumbled upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the string methods to get only the numbers that matter. There are a lot of options available depending upon how messy or formatted your column is:

```
import pandas as pd

df['amount'] = pd.to_numeric(df.amount.str.replace('hours', ''), downcast='integer')
# or 
df['amount'] = pd.to_numeric(df.amount.str[:-5], downcast='integer')
# or
df['amount'] = pd.to_numeric(df.amount.str.extract('(\d+\.?\d*)')[0], downcast='integer')
```

All output:

```
            day  amount
2018-08-23    3      24
2018-08-24    4       8
2018-08-25    5      32
2018-08-26    6      24
2018-08-27    0      24
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the integrity of your data, You can use `pd.to_timedelta` to convert it to duration(timeDelta):

```
>>>df.amount=pd.to_timedelta(df.amount)
>>>df

    date      day   amount
0   2018-08-23  3   1 days 00:00:00
1   2018-08-24  4   0 days 08:00:00
2   2018-08-25  5   1 days 08:00:00
3   2018-08-26  6   1 days 00:00:00
4   2018-08-27  0   1 days 00:00:00
```